# Error importing Parse in React Native (using Back4App)

Tags: react-native, parse-platform, back4app

I am trying to setup Back4App in React native and in the tutorial it says to import Parse like so: `import Parse from "parse/react-native.js"`. But whenever I add this line I get the Error listed below. Anyone have an idea why this would happen? Thanks.

Error: While trying to resolve module `idb-keyval` from file `/Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/parse/lib/react-native/IndexedDBStorageController.js`, the package `/Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/idb-keyval/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/idb-keyval/dist/compat.cjs`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- /Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/idb-keyval/dist/compat.cjs(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- /Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/idb-keyval/dist/compat.cjs/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:243:17)
  at Object.resolve (/Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24)
  at resolve (/Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
  at /Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:412:26
  at Array.reduce ()
  at resolveDependencies (/Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
  at processModule (/Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
  at async addDependency (/Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
  at async Promise.all (index 33)
  at async processModule (/Users/reidtaylor/Sessler2022/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:198:5)

Comment: What's the version of the sdk that you are installing? Are you using expo or cli?

Comment: I am using react cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue by downgrading the version of the parse package to 3.4.0. Apparently others were having this problem as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).